# Give anonymous users access to a report's contents?

Tags: civireport, permissions

I want to make a CiviReport accessible to anonymous users.  I can set the report's "Access" to allow anonymous users, but I want them to see the results of the page without giving them the permission to view any data except what's on the report.

This is how Views works, and Webform-CiviCRM and Caldera Forms allow you to explicitly override contact viewing permissions for selecting anonymous contacts.  Short of overriding a function in the report template, is there a way of making a report's contents available to anonymous viewers?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an ACL(View only) on a group and restricting the report based on [custom permission](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/custompermissions)?

Isn't creating a view or report using dataprocessor not an option?